# finding all functions analytic with $|f(z)|\leq |z+3/2|$ and $f(0)=0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ analytic in $D=\left\{z:|z|<1\right\}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq |z+3/2|$ for all $z\in D$.
Show that:

(a) $|f(1/2)|\leq 1$

(b) Find all functions $f$ that holds (a)

My solution for (a)
Let $g(z)=f(z)/(z+3/2)$. then $g(0)=0$ and $|g(z)|\leq 1$. By Lemma's Schwartz, $|g(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z\in D$ then $|f(z)|\leq |z|(|z+3/2|)$ therefore $|f(1/2)|\leq 1$.

How proves (b)? some hint?

Comment: If you take an arbitrary analytic map $h$ from the unit disc to itself and let $f(z)=z(z+3/2)h(z)$ what can you conclude about $f$?

Comment: That $f$  holds (a) and (b) yes.

Comment: And what you proved in the post shows that $f/(z(z+3/2))$ is analytic and a self map of the unit disc so an $h$ as above...